# Showing Part toolbar in full span in Eclipse e4

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have implemented Eclipse RCP product in 4.5 (Mars) version. There is a part with toolbar. I want to show the part toolbar always in full span (covering the entire width of the part) and not on the part stack (on right side of the part tab).

I tried to add `Part-Toolbar-FullSpan` tag to the Part and also to the part toolbar but it is not helping.
I also tried to create a custom toolbar but that approach did not work out.

Do you know how I can show the part toolbar in full span?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Part-Toolbar-FullSpan` appears to be for the e(fx)clipse JavaFX stack renderer only so it won't work with SWT.

The SWT stack renderer `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer` uses the `setTopRight` method of `CTabFolder` to manage the toolbar. This will only push the toolbar on to a separate row when there not enough space for it on the tab row.

So it looks like the only way to do this would be to define a custom renderer factory and override the stack renderer. Unfortunately for what you want this would be a substantial change to the renderer.

Comment: thanks greg for your help. It looks like a lot of work to do a simple thing. Another option I am thinking about is creating a custom Toolbar and add it at the top of my part. Give it element id so that tool items can be contributed from xmi files. Do you know how I can define such custom toolbar in xmi files?

Comment: I don't see a way to do that in the xmi. You can add a ToolBar using the normal SWT methods but the application model won't know about it.